# Past tense of "to lead"

Tags: discussion, bug

This should not bug me as much as it does, but it is one of my pet peeves, and to see it embedded in an SE site is an affront to my delicate sensibilities.

On the form which we use to report unattributed SE content, the instructive text in the field for the salient search terms is:

> `paste the search terms that lead you to the other site here`

Is the war over? Have we lost *led* forever? I suppose a case could be made for the present tense, but it would not convince me.

Is there a more appropriate venue for this mini-rant? (I know `bug` is an overtag, but I couldn't find a lesser term.)

Comment: Usually, when a change you propose will/could/should affect more than one SE site, you go to [meta.SE]. Proposals there are more often looked at and there are wording-change proposals there already. I'd tag it as [bug] and [wording], and also check it with the meta veterans in [Tavern on the meta](http://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/89/tavern-on-the-meta), to evaluate the feedback it will get beforehand. Some requests are valid, but too minor, and some requests aren't valid when you think they are.

Comment: Somehow I think this is a great question on the main site! :)

Comment: I don't see that as a fault.  If you enter the search terms again - for example the SE staff testing your flag - then the search terms *lead* to the other site.

Comment: Of course. The writer did not intend to use the past tense. That is certainly possible, and even if that was not the writer's intention, there is no way to prove it. I assume that since the person submitting the report is describing what happened when she conducted her search, the past tense is intended.